# How to write count formula in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm developing a report and i need to do a count for a several fields like "Success" and "Failure" in my report. I have a column "status" and "Name" in my database. The "Status" column contains the values of 0 and 1,in which 0 represents Failure and 1 represents Success.

In crystal reports i need to do count for success and failure for every names and also want to do group by names..
for example:
             `Names  Success  Failure`

```
                 xxxx     10       5
```

Guide me with some formulas to calculate like this in crystal reports

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Group by Name first.
2. On group header write 3 names `Names` `Success` `Failure`
3. In detail part write 2 formulas.
   First formula

   If status=0
   Then 0
   else 1
   In the same way create another formula for `status=1`

Now go the created formula and go to `Insert Summay`, Now insert summary on the group.